# Using dispatch_once

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have the following code:

```
  static NSDictionary * errorDescriptions = nil;

+ (NSString *) errorsFromCode: (WPErrorCode) code {

    if(errorDescriptions == nil) {
        errorDescriptions  =  @{[NSNumber numberWithInt: InvalidCar]:  NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Car is invalid.", @"WePay", @"validation: invalid car"), ...
    }

    return [errorDescriptions objectForKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt: code]];
}
```

I got advice to change the code above to:

```
+ (NSString *) errorsFromCode: (WPErrorCode) code {
    static NSDictionary * errorDescriptions = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        errorDescriptions  =  @{[NSNumber numberWithInt: InvalidCar]:  NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Car is invalid.", @"WePay", @"validation: invalid car"), ...
     }
     return [errorDescriptions objectForKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt: code]];
}
```

Why is that the case? Why do I have to use dispatch_once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use it, but what you put in the block will only be executed once in a thread-safe manner.

You don't need, and shouldn't have, the `if errorDescriptions == nil` check if you will be using `dispatch_once`.

Answer (score 4):

dispatch_once is used to create objects whose initialization is expensive, or to block other threads while the object is being initialized. None of these situations apply here. It doesn't matter how many times you initialize that object, and it's not expensive as to require special treatment. It looks pointless to me. Brad is right to say the if in the second block is superfluous.

Comment: if you aren't using ARC you could leak the first dict created during a race condition.

Comment: If the code isn't using ARC, it's going to crash the second time the method is run, @BradAllred, because the dictionary is in an autorelease pool.

Comment: Yup, it would be `@[@{...} retain]` because the literal syntax creates an autoreleased object.

Comment: @JoshCaswell also a good point :) Still good to remember that if you find yourself working on non-ARC code.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely to prevent a race condition.